# How to call methods in main method from different class

Tags: java

I have to create two classes,

first class should have:

•   3 attributes (all different types e.g. int, LocalDate, String, double…)

•   1 constructor

•   1 toString() method (provide a String representation of the Object)

•   Setter and getter methods for each attribute

and second class should have:

This should be done by writing a second class called TestMyClass. This class must have a main method and at least four(4) other methods used to do the testing. When main is called, all tests are run (by calling those test methods) and the results should be reported to the screen. There is ONE test per method.

In a method that does the testing, you may,

•   Build the object(s) to be tested

•   Tell the user what is being tested

•   Tell the user the data being used

•   Tell the user the expected result

•   Report the actual result

•   Return true if the test was successful, else return false.

Facing issue in creating a second class. Any help will be really appreciated.

My First class code:

public class Banks 
{

```
 int id;
 double amount;
 String name;

public Banks(int id, double amount, String name)
{
  this.id = id;
  this.amount = amount;
  this.name = name;
}

public void setId( int id) {
  this.id = 12;
 }

public void setAmount(double amount) {
  this.amount = 3000.00;
}

public void setName( String name) {
  this.name = "ANZ";
}

public int getId(){

   return id;

}

public double getAmount(){

    return amount;

}

public String getName(){

    return name; 

}

public String toString()
{
    return id + " " + amount + " " + name;
}
```

}

Comment: what kind of issue did you faced? and what have you tried? for the second class

Comment: "Facing issue in creating a second class" is not a question we can answer.  What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The second class is being used to test the getters and setters methods in your first class. It would make testing easier if you added some validation into your setter methods so you had something to test against. In your second class, you could create objects of type Banks and then manipulate the arguments to ensure they are working. Below is slightly altered version of your first class with some ideas for a second class.

BANKS CLASS

```
    int id;
    double amount;
    String name;

    public Banks(int id, double amount, String name){
      setId(id);
      setAmount(amount);
      setName(name);
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        if(id <= 0) {
            System.out.println("ID must be greater than 0");
        }
        this.id = id;
     }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        if(amount < 0){
            System.out.println("Amount must be greater than or equal to 0");
        }
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId(){
       return id;
    }

    public double getAmount(){
        return amount;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return id + " " + amount + " " + name;
    }
}
```

TESTMYCLASS CLASS

```
 public class TestMyClass {

public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("Test 1");
    testSetId();
    System.out.println("Test 2");
    testSetAmount();
    System.out.println("Test 3");
    testSetName();
}

public static void testConstructor() {
    Banks testObject1 = new Banks(1, 500, "Mario");
    System.out.println(testObject1);
}

public static void testSetId() {
    Banks testObject2 = new Banks(1, 500, "Mario");
    testObject2.setId(0);
}

public static void testSetAmount() {
    Banks testObject3 = new Banks(1, 500, "Toad");
    testObject3.setAmount(-25);
}

public static void testSetName() {
    Banks testObject4 = new Banks(1, 500, "Luigi");
    System.out.printf("Old object3 name: %s%n", testObject4.getName());
    testObject4.setName("Mr Luigi");
    System.out.printf("New object3 name: %s%n", testObject4.getName());
}
```

}